# Post vs Post_via_redirect in Rails 4 not behaving in expected way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I'm stumped in a particular part of M. Hartl's Rails guide (Ch 8) with integration
testing. I am trying to validate user login/logout, here's my testing code(not working):

```
##doesnt work
test "should display user logout behavior" do
  get login_path
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 3
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 2
  post_via_redirect login_path, session: {email: @user.email, 
    password: "password"}
  assert_redirected_to @user
  assert logged_in?
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  delete logout_path
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'static_pages/home'
  assert_not logged_in?
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 2
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 3
end
```

however, making these modifications will make it work:

```
#works
test "should display user logout behavior" do
  get login_path
  assert_template 'sessions/new'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 3
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 2
  post login_path, session: {email: @user.email, 
    password: "password"}
  assert_redirected_to @user
  follow_redirect!
  assert logged_in?
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  delete logout_path
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'static_pages/home'
  assert_not logged_in?
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 2
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path, count: 3
end
```

The part that fails is the `assert_redirected_to`. I have checked via `response.body` and everything gets rendered as expected...

Essentially the only difference is `post` v. `post_via_redirect`. 
Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a3b1105ada3da64acfa3843b164b14b734456a50/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L92) of 'via_redirect', I believe they should work as all they
are doing is following redirects until there are none left. In addition, I have no further redirects than those I'm testing for:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by email: params[:session][:email]
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password].downcase)
      log_in(user)
      redirect_to user_path(user.id)
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid username/password combination"
      render 'new'  
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

From that standpoint, here's the questions:

- Do the redirection options get lost whenever we call a `via_redirect`, and thus testing 
  'assert_redirected_to @user' fails?
- Is there one more jump I'm making when running `via_redirect`? All I see the `follow_redirect!` doing is running `get(response.location)`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting here for completeness, but I was able to find my own answer. Here it is:

- Do the redirection options get lost whenever we call a `via_redirect`, and thus testing `assert_redirected_to @user` fails?

**Yes!** Because of the way `request_via_redirect` works:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb, line 92
def request_via_redirect(http_method, path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = nil)
  process(http_method, path, parameters, headers_or_env)
  follow_redirect! while redirect?
  status
end
```

After all the redirects are processed, you will end up with a `@response` object that will be compared in the following way:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/response.rb, line 55
def assert_redirected_to(options = {}, message=nil)
  #....
  redirect_is       = normalize_argument_to_redirection(@response.location)
  redirect_expected = normalize_argument_to_redirection(options)
```

After your final redirect is process, your `response_code` will be `200` and your `@response.location` will be `nil`. So yes, your response headers will be lost and `assert_redirected_to` will be false.

- Is there one more jump I'm making when running `via_redirect`? All I see the `follow_redirect!` doing is running `get(response.location)`.

**It depends**, with your router/controller settings you may have more than one redirect. No matter the case, you will end up with a `@response` that has no `location` redirected (if you're not in an infinite redirect loop) and you won't have your headers available.

Thanks to  @dre-hh for giving me the insight to start thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the issue is just within

```
 assert_redirected_to @user
```

This assertions just checks the response headers of the previous action, which is fine. However if you follow the redirect the previous redirect response is already gone and you have the response after the redirect.

As this is an integration test there is no need to check every step of it. Because if the redirect fails the next assertion

assert logged_in?

will also fail.

So if using post_via_redirect just check something which applies for the next page.

Comment: Thanks! It does make sense now to not test for the redirection; instead test for an expected changes in layouts. I was able dive into the issue and figured out my answer.